# Extract variable names and offsets from a compound C struct

Tags: c, variables, struct, wireshark

I am working on a Wireshark plugin that must decode a large packet that is created by writing a struct into the packet.  If I am able to know the variable names and offset of the original structure, I would then be able to decode the data without regard to the original compiler.  The struct is large (> 650 bytes) and contains compound elements and typedefs.

The construction of the struct changes based on the version of software generating the data.  I have access to the raw header files and the compiler used in creating the software, thus I can create a framework to extract the detail I need for use in Wireshark.

I have been successful in hand coding the decode for a few of the variables and offsets needed but the size and complexity of the structure require more automation than I can do by hand.

Any suggestion on how to do this would be most welcome.

Comment: Suggestion: "struct is large (> 650 bytes) and contains compound elements and typedefs."  --> Posting that structure (or a facsimile of it) would lead to improved quality of answers.  Posting sample code of "I would then be able to decode the data" would help too to clarify your coding goals.

Comment: For the offsets, [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) can help. For more than that, I’d check if the compiler offered an API to access this information; I know Clang does and I’m pretty sure GCC does. What compiler is being used.

Comment: "without regard to the original compiler": Different compilers and different compiler settings will align the data differently. This sounds like a problem more complicated than you think?

Comment: I expect the correct answer is to compile with debugging information and somehow extract this from that. I don’t know enough about the various debugging information standards to help with that, though I wouldn’t be surprised if some standard tool could do it.

Comment: The compiler used is gcc in 32 bit linux. I know that I can use `offset` to get what I need but I was hoping for some sort of automated script or code that would list all struct elements and type, then use that to loop through the generated list and using `offset` to get the required info.

Comment: I don't know if your protocol is amenable to ASN.1 or not, and I don't personally have much experience with ASN.1, so I don't this will help you or not, but have you looked into ASN.1?

For example, see: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Asn2wrs,  https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=tree;f=epan/dissectors/asn1;hb=HEAD, ...

Comment: @alindber When I said “edit this into the question”, I meant you should hit the edit link under the question tags and put it there, not as a comment. People are more likely to see it if it’s in the question itself.

Comment: If you do find a way to automate this, using my method below or any other method, I’d be interested in whatever tool you create. I have a lot of smaller `struct`s I’d like to teach to Wireshark if it were easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven’t used this myself beyond what you see here, especially not in complex situations; I’m only posting this as an answer because it’s better than the current lack-of-an-answer, but don’t be surprised if there are better options or critical information missing from this answer.

---

It looks like all the information you need is available in the debug information when you compile with the `-g` flag. You can see it in close-to-raw format with

```sh
objdump -Wi object_file.o
```

This isn’t the most useful format, and there are tools to analyze it for you. One of them is `pahole` ([sources](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/devel/pahole/pahole.git/tree/), [LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/335942/), [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pahole)); I haven’t used it enough to recommend it, but it seems at least worth investigating further. It may be under `dwarves` or something in your package manager because it’s part of a collection of related tools for handling DWARF debug information.

It seems to output exactly the information you want, with a few flags. It’s easier to parse the original C, but it still looks more like it’s intended for humans than for computer parsing; I haven’t found a flag that looks purely intended for machine parsing. Here’s an example `pahole` run:

Input `struct.c`

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct simple {
  int32_t i32;
  char c;
  uint64_t u64;
} simple_object;

struct complicated {
  struct simple nested_simple;
  union {
    float union_float;
    uint32_t union_int;
  } nested_union;
  struct {
    double d;
    char c;
  } nested_struct;
  char some_chars[5];
  struct simple_packed nested_simple_packed;
  enum {COMPLICATED_ENUM1, COMPLICATED_ENUM2, COMPLICATED_ENUM3} enumeration;
} complicated_object;
```

After running

```
gcc -g structs.c -c -o structs.o 
pahole --expand_types structs.o
```

you get

```
struct simple {
        /* typedef int32_t -> __int32_t */ int                        i32;               /*     0     4 */
        char                       c;                                                    /*     4     1 */

        /* XXX 3 bytes hole, try to pack */

        /* typedef uint64_t -> __uint64_t */ long unsigned int          u64;             /*     8     8 */

        /* size: 16, cachelines: 1, members: 3 */
        /* sum members: 13, holes: 1, sum holes: 3 */
        /* last cacheline: 16 bytes */
};
struct complicated {
        struct simple {
                /* typedef int32_t -> __int32_t */ int                i32;               /*     0     4 */
                char               c;                                                    /*     4     1 */

                /* XXX 3 bytes hole, try to pack */

                /* typedef uint64_t -> __uint64_t */ long unsigned int  u64;             /*     8     8 */
        } nested_simple; /*     0    16 */
        union {
                float              union_float;                                          /*           4 */
                /* typedef uint32_t -> __uint32_t */ unsigned int       union_int;       /*           4 */
        } nested_union;                                                                  /*    16     4 */

        /* XXX 4 bytes hole, try to pack */

        struct {
                double             d;                                                    /*    24     8 */
                char               c;                                                    /*    32     1 */
        } nested_struct;                                                                 /*    24    16 */
        char                       some_chars[5];                                        /*    40     5 */

        /* XXX 3 bytes hole, try to pack */

        enum {
                COMPLICATED_ENUM1 = 0,
                COMPLICATED_ENUM2 = 1,
                COMPLICATED_ENUM3 = 2,
        } enumeration;                                                                   /*    48     4 */

        /* size: 56, cachelines: 1, members: 5 */
        /* sum members: 45, holes: 2, sum holes: 7 */
        /* padding: 4 */
        /* last cacheline: 56 bytes */
};
```